# Android Twiiter authorization and back button behavior

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, twitter4j, android-browser

I'm working on Twitter integration into my Android app. I am using `twitter4j` lib. My application has a single activity with `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. There is a "share" button in my activity that is supposed to perform Twitter post on behalf of the user.

At the moment, behavior of my application is as follows:

1. User presses "share" button and Twitter authorization process begins.
2. After I got oauth request token, I launch the browser:

   ```
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
   ```
3. User presses "authorize" button in browser and (thanks to callback url) control returns back to my activity calling `onNewIntent(Intent)`.

Everything is cool. But if I press "back" button in my activity after step 3, I expect to fall back to Android main screen (launch screen). Instead of this, I fall to browser (that I have launched on step 2.).

My question is: Is it normal? If not, how do I fix it?

Having launched `adb.exe`, I found activity stack as follows:

After step 2 (when browser is on the screen):

`Running activities (most recent first):`

```
TaskRecord{426729a8 #94 A android.task.browser}
  Run #2: ActivityRecord{414204d8 com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity}
TaskRecord{4252bdb0 #107 A com.mycompany.myapp}
  Run #1: ActivityRecord{41428ed8 com.mycompany.myapp/.MyActivity}
TaskRecord{41716f90 #2 A com.sec.android.app.launcher}
  Run #0: ActivityRecord{41584088 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
```

After step 3: (when my activity is on the screen, before I press back button):

`Running activities (most recent first):`

```
TaskRecord{4252bdb0 #107 A com.mycompany.myapp}
  Run #2: ActivityRecord{41428ed8 com.mycompany.myapp/.MyActivity}
TaskRecord{426729a8 #94 A android.task.browser}
  Run #1: ActivityRecord{414204d8 com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity}
TaskRecord{41716f90 #2 A com.sec.android.app.launcher}
  Run #0: ActivityRecord{41584088 com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to finish the browser activity, so there would be nothing on the stack previous the callback to the app screeen.